# Iterate through list of files and calculate the correlation between them in R

Tags: r, loops, correlation, raster

I'm trying to iterate through many raster files in R (using raster package), calculate the correlation between them in a running fashion.  I need to do 3 primary things iteratively:

```
c <- cor(x,y)
sum <- x+y
deltacor <- 1-(cor([i],sum)) # where i = next raster in list
```

Here is what I've got to set up the loops:

```
require(raster)

files = list.files(getwd(),pattern="*.asc") # get files
lsfiles <-lapply(files,function(x) raster(x)) # import them as rasters

for (x in lsfiles){
    x <- na.omit(getValues(i)) # cannot ignore NA in other attempted ways
```

Do I need a j loop to grab the second file from the list and then correlate i and j? Is there some easier way of looping through a directory of files, calculating the correlation between two of them and then those 2 and the next 1? Ideally I would not load all the rasters into memory at once.

Ideas and/or help greatly appreciated

Comment: In a running fashion (with some order specified, presumably), or pairwise? In your comment about this elsewhere it sounded like you were interested in pairwise correlations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated with answer for anyone with similar problems:

```
require(raster)
setwd ('/foobar')

x <- raster(foobar.asc)
solution <-raster(solution.asc)

for (file in list.files(getwd(),pattern="*.asc",full.names=TRUE)){
    file <- raster(file)
    file <- na.omit(getValues(file))
    rs <- file+x               # just uses first file in list (x) rolling sum
    deltac <- 1-(cor(rs,x))    # delta from current sum and previous sum
    tc <- cor(solution,rs)     # actual correlation with solution
    x <- rs                    # update x by making it the previous sum
print(tc)                      # actual correlation
print (deltac)                 # how correlated was last sum with new sum
}
```

Comment: Note that your pattern, `*.asc`, will match file names such as `mascot.jpg`. The pattern you're probably after is `\\.asc$`.